# NodeJS/Mongoose: Pushing ObjectID to Front of Array

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to push an object ID to the front of array. Currently, when I perform this `user.posts.push(Post._id)`, I would get `"posts" : [ ObjectId("1") ]`.

However, if I try to push another ID into the array, I would get `"posts" : [ ObjectId("1"), ObjectId("2")]`, instead of `"posts" : [ ObjectId("2"), ObjectId("1")]` which is what I want.

I tried searching for other ways but most of them are quite complicated. The only way I know is to use `reverse()` after retrieving from the database, and before rendering on HTML. Is there a smarter/proper way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use unshift

```
user.posts.unshift(Post._id)
```